# how to make a smooth animation when listview is doing RequestLayout()

Tags: android, listview, animation

I've implement a rotation animation on a button, it plays well.

When I put it on the action bar, then in the content of window calls `RequestLayout()` on a `ListView`, the animation begins to drop frame.

Since `RequestLayout()` will hang the main thread, it comes to two solutions:

1. manually update `ListView` row by row, free the main thread every 40ms
2. find a "high priority" animation, which can keep playing even if the main thread is busy

Although the first solution is worth to try, I have no idea how to implement the second solution.

Hope for your suggestions.  ;)

In my actual project, the animation is a simple rotation animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<rotate 
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="500" /> 

</set>
```

The code below is a demo I used to test ListView. Although it has nothing to do with the animation above, when I update the data of ListView, I can see android begin to drop frame via a GPU developer's tools provided by the phone.

In the actual project, the animation appears laggy when the data of listview is updating.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public static int N_ROW = 200;

    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayList<String> mData1 = null;
    private ArrayList<String> mData2 = null;
    private ArrayList<String> mData3 = null;
    private int mCurrData = 1;
    private Random r = new Random();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        /// random, 3-digits test data to display in listview
        mData1 = genRandomData(0);

        /// longer test data 
        mData2 = genRandomData(100000);

        /// another test data to change content of textView but do not change the content length
        mData3 = genRandomData(0);

        final ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_name, mData1);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        /// change the text using standard notifyDataSetChanged
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCurrData == 1) {
                    mCurrData = 3;
                    adapter.updateData(mData3);
                } else {
                    mCurrData = 1;
                    adapter.updateData(mData1);
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });


        /// change the text length between long <---> short  & invalidate()
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_invalidate);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCurrData == 2) {
                    mCurrData = 1;
                    adapter.updateData(mData1);
                } else {
                    mCurrData = 2;
                    adapter.updateData(mData2);
                }

                refreshVisibleListViewArea();
                mListView.invalidate();
            }
        });


        /// change the text using row by row modification & invalidate()
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_invalidate2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mCurrData == 3) {
                    mCurrData = 1;
                    adapter.updateData(mData1);
                } else {
                    mCurrData = 3;
                    adapter.updateData(mData3);
                }
                refreshVisibleListViewArea();
                mListView.invalidate();
            }
        });


        /// do nothing but invalidate()
        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_invalidate3);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                refreshVisibleListViewArea();
                mListView.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<String> genRandomData(int offset) {
        ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < N_ROW * 4; ++ i) {
            String a = "I_" + r.nextInt(N_ROW * 4 + offset);
            tmp.add(a);
        }

        return tmp;
    }

    private void refreshVisibleListViewArea() {
        int s = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int e = mListView.getLastVisiblePosition();
        for (int i = s; i <= e; ++ i) {
            View v = mListView.getChildAt(i - s);
            mListView.getAdapter().getView(i, v, mListView);
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


    private ArrayList<String> mData;
    private Context mContext;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> data) {
        super(context, resource, data);
        mContext = context;
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder vh = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_name, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder();

            vh.v1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.v1);
            vh.v2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.v2);
            vh.v3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.v3);
            vh.v4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.v4);

            convertView.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (vh.v1.getText() != mData.get(position * 4)) {
            vh.v1.setText(mData.get(position * 4));
        }
        if (vh.v2.getText() != mData.get(position * 4 + 1)) {
            vh.v2.setText(mData.get(position * 4 + 1));
        }
        if (vh.v3.getText() != mData.get(position * 4 + 2)) {
            vh.v3.setText(mData.get(position * 4 + 2));
        }
        if (vh.v4.getText() != mData.get(position * 4 + 3)) {
            vh.v4.setText(mData.get(position * 4 + 3));
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return MainActivity.N_ROW;
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<String> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView v1;
        TextView v2;
        TextView v3;
        TextView v4;
    }

}
```

list_item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/v3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/v4"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#0ff"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why would `RequestLayout()` hang he main thread?

Comment: Can you please show your code what are you trying to do exactly

Comment: @pskink: I mean after I call RequestLayout(), it appears that main thread hang for a while (to update listview). I will paste the snippets of code in the thread

Comment: why are you calling `getView` in `refreshVisibleListViewArea` ?

Comment: getView() will call convertView.getTag(), then update the 4 textViews in list item. If miss this call, visible area of ListView won't be updated correctly.

Comment: the correct way is to update your data model and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @pskink call notifyDataSetChanged() will end with a RequestLayout(); then measure(in this section, obtainView() is called) -> layout -> draw; which do a lot of work and cause the animation drop frame

Comment: no idea what you are talking about...

Answer (score 0):

after some profiling works, I believe in the situation I described above, there are too much TextViews to update at the same time, so a lot of resources is occupied by opengl draw.

Decieded to split the udpate into smaller ones.

---

Finally I use surface view to impletement the animation effects. ;)